# How to pass a list as parameter for varargs?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

```
List<String> strings;
void takeParams(String... params);
```

How can I pass the list into that a method only taking varargs?

`strings.toArray();` is not possible as it returns `Object[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method to create an array from the list, and pass it.

```
takeParams(strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]));
```

Comment: in the case of Redis, it's not working for me. my command is `syncCommands.mget(redisKeys.toArray(new String[redisKeys.size()])); `and I get error msg `[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String.` Any help?