# How to pass a List of byte[] as a varargs parameter?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

My question is very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951470/how-to-pass-a-list-as-parameter-for-varargs). But it's not the same.
I have a method that accepts varargs with a signature like

```
static void doSomething(byte[]... values)
```

And a List of byte[] that I want to send to that method.

```
List<byte[]> myList;
```

How do I convert `myList` to `byte[]` varargs to send to `doSomething`?

I thought it would be something like

```
doSomething(myList.toArray(new Byte[][0]));
```

but that did not work - It says `unexpected token at 0]))`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but that did not work" - so what happened?

Comment: It says "unexpected token" at 0])) so I'm guessing it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: try `doSomething(myList.toArray(new byte[0]));` (you have one bracket pair/dimension too much)

Comment: no, the varargs that is expected is already an array. See, `doSomething(byte[]... values)`

Comment: Right, please edit the error message into your question. *Always* include the error in a question - otherwise it's like going to the doctor and saying "I think I'm ill" and expecting a diagnosis without providing any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `Byte` and `byte` are different types
- The syntax for creating the array-of-arrays is incorrect - it should be `new byte[0][]`. Arrays of arrays are annoying in that respect, to be honest. I can certainly understand why you'd expect to put the `[0]` at the end, but in this case it's just not that way...

With that change in place, it's fine:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<byte[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new byte[10]);
        myList.add(new byte[5]);
        doSomething(myList.toArray(new byte[0][]));
    }

    static void doSomething(byte[]... values) {
        System.out.printf("Array contained %d values%n", values.length);
    }
}
```